# What would happen if someone got stabbed with this taser sword?

Tags: physics, anatomy, electricity, medicine

In my world there is a weapon that's basically a magical high voltage, high current sword.

It accumulates electricity and when it touches a flesh it instantly discharges, the electricity is supposed to have a current of 20 amps and voltage of 1000V of DC (the electricity is supposed to flow from the blade to the ground)

So my question is. What would happen if someone got stabbed with it in the thigh, and the electricity flowed through an entire leg to the ground?

Comment: One imagines they would phone the police. "Some nutter is stabbing people with an electric sword!"

Comment: What exactly is the worldbuilding issue or problem you're trying to solve? This boils down to a question of what happens when you electrocute someone with a specific amount of electricity. Take a look at the [tour] the [help] and [what Worldbuilding is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about).

Comment: Well, I'm trying to estimate how much a weapon like this would impact my world, and for that I need to know how it would actually work, so it may not be a direct worldbuilding question, but it still affects my world.

Comment: @John not quite. It might be a non-damaging stroke, like a glancing blow. Even when hitting with a lethal or deep wound it's interesting, as they might flail or simply require less time and effort to disable your opponent.

Comment: since you are referring to stab rather than cut or slash motion, i assume it probably has the same effect when you stab a person using nail in the thigh and then electrocute them using it. but it also depend on the victim equipment though like does the victim wear any metal equipment? naked? or has leather/latex/rubber equipment with it?

Comment: why would the sword discharge into the leg, are they barefoot? A leather boot is a decent insulator.

Comment: I have to correct myself, with 20 amps and 1000V the sword is more or less irrelevant. that is far far into the lethal range for electricity. there are only two questions what kind of shoes they are wearing and how to keep the user alive as they are just as likely to be shocked as the victim.

Answer (score 2):

## The sword would do more damage than the electricity.

Something with "20 amps" written on the side refers to its maximum before overloading. If the resistance between thigh and ground is 50ohms, the sword would be operating at its maximum current of 20amp.

Typical body to body resistance of a human is 300 ohms, but the skin adds another few thousand. Any shoes would add tens to hundreds of thousands. These lower the current that can run. Adding all these resistances means the flow through the body would be in the order of 10ma, barely detectable.

The entire circuit would be equivalent to trying to run 1000vdc through your shoe soles. Nothing will happen.

If shoeless, you will get some current flowing, but it wont cause constant twitching or spasms, but heat and burns around the wound and soles of feet. Maybe a jolt when first connected but that'd be indistinguishable from the pain of being stabbed.

Depending on humidity, There may be a spark gap of about 1-2mm before the sword contacts the skin, that will burn a small dot and do more electrical damage then when it connects.

Ac causes the muscles to twich. That's what's in your tasers and your electrostim muscle equipment. Switch your sword to ac and they'll twitch like you're probably expecting. 1000 volts ac thigh to ground will definitely knock you over, may be fatal, but first aid has a decent chance of saving the day.

Ac electricity can set up irregualr heart rhythms which can kill you hours later if untreated. So this surprise later death may be relevant to your plot.